# Django Rest Framework: Defining a view's queryset, why hit the DB at startup

Tags: django-rest-framework

The [DRF View docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#updatemodelmixin) have this example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from myapp.serializers import UserSerializer
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAdminUser

class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
```

From reading the Django Docs, whenever `.all()` is encountered, it hits the database.
This means I suspect the DB is being hit when the view id being created, which seems not ideal to me.

The [source code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py) at least shows that it revaluates the queryset, so its not just using the cached versoin when instantiated:

```
    assert self.queryset is not None, (
        "'%s' should either include a `queryset` attribute, "
        "or override the `get_queryset()` method."
        % self.__class__.__name__
    )

    queryset = self.queryset
    if isinstance(queryset, QuerySet):
        # Ensure queryset is re-evaluated on each request.
        queryset = queryset.all()
    return queryset
```

My question is, wouldn't it be better to set the `queryset` in their example as follows:

```py
class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects  # <--- i.e. drop the .all()
    ...
```

This way it doesnt hit the DB at start up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django doesn't make DB call when you define queryset. DB will be called only when queryset is used. See details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated).

You can check it by this code:

```
from django.db import connection
print(len(connection.queries)) # total count of query calls, return 0
queryset = User.objects.all()
print(len(connection.queries)) # return 0
len(queryset) # only here we actually use queryset and send DB call
print(len(connection.queries)) # return 1
```

So you can use your initial code, it doesn't make any additional DB calls.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/optimization/#understand-cached-attributes it says `callable attributes cause DB lookups every time: >>> entry.authors.all()   # query performed
>>> entry.authors.all()   # query performed again`

Comment: @run_the_race yes if you write just `User.objects.all()` it will be evaluated immediately, since Python thinks you need this value right now. But if you use it as an assignment `queryset = User.objects.all()` Python will not execute the query before you access `queryset` value. Here is another example https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy